# How can i get all Gallery Photoes from Internal Storage?

Tags: android, android-image

I want to get all gallary photoes in my App. For External storage i can get right output. But for internal storage of devices i cannot get anything.

I have some part of code for **External storage** which is :

```
      final String[] photoColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String sort = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

                Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, photoColumn,
                        null, null, sort);
 if (imagecursor != null && imagecursor.getCount() > 0) {

                while (imagecursor.moveToNext()) {
                //My Task

                }
}
```

For Internal storage i have replace

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

with

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

but i cannot get any thing?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: The Gallery app has no access to internal storage. Hence dont ask such things.